# Unable to switch from hybrid app to com.mobile.safari with Appium & Protractor

Tags: facebook, angularjs, cordova, protractor, appium

I have an ionic/angularjs/cordova application that uses the cordova facebook plugin. I have appium with cucumber and protractor setup and I can test everything on the app within the simulator. In the app itself I have facebook authentication setup and I am trying to test this on an iOS simulator.

If you look at this step below

```
And I input my facebook credentials
```

The app will redirect to facebook mobile web, waits for the browser to load and then will infinitely refresh itself.

When I console.log the browser url after the cordova app redirects to facebook on safari, the url is the app's local file path and now the browser url of facebook.

config.js

```
exports.config = {

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'iOS',
    app: '/Users/username/Projects/app-directory/platforms/ios/build/emulator/appname.app',
    deviceName: 'iPhone Simulator',
    'appium-version': '1.3.0-beta1',
    version: '8.0',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '8.0',
    autoWebview: true,
    autoWebviewTimeout: 10
  },

  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100',

  onPrepare: function() {
    var wd = require('wd'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
  },

  framework: 'cucumber',

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: '../features/**/*.js',
    format: 'pretty'
  },

  specs: [ '../features/*.feature' ]
};
```

root.feature

```
Feature: Root Screen
  As a user who is not logged in
  I want to be greeted with a menu screen
  So that I know where to sign up or login

  Scenario: Successfully logging into the app through facebook
    Given I am a user on facebook
    When I click on the facebook button
    And I input my facebook credentials
    And I accept the facebook permissions
    Then I should be at the home screen
```

root steps

```
var rootSteps = function() {

  this.Given(/^I am a user on facebook$/, function (done) {
    this.app.createFbUser().then(done); // helper that returns a promise and creates a fb test user object and sets it to this.app.fbUser;
  });

  this.When(/^I click on the facebook button$/, function (done) {
    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[ng-click="fbLogin()"]')).click().then(done);
  });

  this.When(/^I input my facebook credentials$/, function (done) {
    browser.sleep( 8000 );  // wait for facebook to completely load

    wdBrowser.contexts().then(function(ctxs) {
      var webCtx = _(ctxs).find(function(ctx) { return ctx.match(/WEBVIEW/)});
      wdBrowser.context(webCtx) ;
    }).then(function() {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
      var emailElem = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('email'));
      var passwordElem = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('password'));
      var submitElem = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('login'));

      emailElem.sendKeys(this.app.fbUser.email);
      passwordElem.sendKeys(this.app.fbUser.password);
      submitElem.click().then(done);
    });
  });

  this.When(/^I accept the facebook permissions$/, function (done) {
    done.pending();
  });

  this.Then(/^I should be at the home screen$/, function (done) {
    done.pending();
  })
};

module.exports = rootSteps;
```

Here is the error logs from Appium.

```
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_1"],"sessionId":"a93509a3-3cce-4f03-be58-c59474b40e92"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/a93509a3-3cce-4f03-be58-c59474b40e92/contexts 200 2.140 ms - 98 {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_1"],"sessionId":"a93509a3-3cce-4f03-be58-c59474b40e92"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Got a blank data response from debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument" {"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:34459","WIRIsApplicationProxyKey":false,"WIRApplicationNameKey":"Safari","WIRApplicationBundleIdentifierKey":"com.apple.mobilesafari","WIRIsApplicationActiveKey":1},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationConnected:"}
info: [REMOTE] We were notified that we connected to possibly the wrong application. Ignoring for now and hoping we're going to retry looking for apps
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is currently not possible. According to the Appium team, xcode instruments loads up the app and currently can not change the bundle id.